# How to restart deployment in Kubernetes helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I deployed the consul client on my k8s cluster using helm .

```
sudo helm install hi-consul hashicorp/consul -n consul-client  -f config.yaml
```

[image]

One of the pods is not working now. Is there a way to restart that pod in the helm?

Thanks

Comment: you can use the kubectl delete pod command, followed by the name of the pod, to delete the pod. This will cause Kubernetes to automatically create a new instance of the pod  `kubectl delete pod {NAME}`

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the POD with `kubectl delete <POD name> -n <Namespace name>`

If you want all pods to be restarted you can use the `kubectl rollout restart deployment <deployment name> -n <Namespace name>`